# SPARK SQL Self join reading twice from HDFS block

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is a sample snippet of the fairly complex query that I am executing with Spark 1.3.1 (window functions are not an option in this version). This query is reading around 18K blocks from HDFS twice and then doing a shuffle with 18K partitions.

Since it is a Self Join and since both the tables are grouped by and joined by the same keys, I was assuming that the all the keys would be co-located on the same partition for the join, possibly avoiding the Shuffle.

Is there a way around to avoid reading twice and also to avoid shuffle? Can I Repartition the input sets by default partitioner or use the group by separately on a DataFrame rather than executing it as single query?  Thanks.

```scala
val df = hiveContext.sql("""SELECT  
          EVNT.COL1  
         ,EVNT.COL2  
         ,EVNT.COL3  
         ,MAX(CASE WHEN (EVNT.COL4 = EVNT_DRV.min_COL4) THEN EVNT.COL5  
             ELSE -2147483648 END) AS COL5  
   FROM  
    TRANS_EVNT EVNT  
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  
      COL1  
     ,COL2  
     ,COL3  
     ,COL6  
     ,MIN(COL4) AS min_COL4  
    FROM  
     TRANS_EVNT  
    WHERE partition_key between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'   
     GROUP BY  
      COL1  
     ,COL2  
     ,COL3  
     ,COL6) EVNT_DRV  
   ON   
        EVNT.COL1 = EVNT_DRV.COL1   
    AND EVNT.COL2 = EVNT_DRV.COL2   
    AND EVNT.COL3 = EVNT_DRV.COL3   
    AND EVNT.COL6 = EVNT_DRV.COL6  
   WHERE partition_key between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'   
   GROUP BY  
    EVNT.COL1  
   ,EVNT.COL2  
   ,EVNT.COL3  
   ,EVNT.COL6""")
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323. I tried caching the DataFrame with the filtered resultset but it didn't do anything differently. 

Then I tried to repartition the DF to 1000 partitions, which is skipping the second Read. I am using the below.    
<code>
val TRANS_EVNT_RAW = hiveContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM TRANS_EVNT WHERE partition_key  >= '2015-01-01' and partition_key  < '2015-01-31' """)  

val TRANS_EVNT_repart = TRANS_EVNT_RAW.repartition(1000)    

TRANS_EVNT_repart.registerTempTable("TRANS_EVNT")
</code>

Comment: There are below Stages during job execution  
1. Repartition at DataFrame -> tasks 18,100;    
2. mapPartition at DataFrame -> tasks 1,000;   
3. mapPartition at DataFrame -> tasks 1,000;  
4. mapPartition at DataFrame -> tasks 500;  
5. mapPartition at DataFrame -> tasks 500;   (i have set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions as 500);  

I believe this can be further optimized but do not know how. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: @zhang zhan, would you take a look at the above question please?